# iTunes Api to Get BIO

Tags: itunes

Does `iTunes` provides any API to fetch bio information?

From this documentation [iTunes Search API](http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html#searchexamples), I can search for any movie, track etc. But i cant find anything to get Bio.

https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=jackson&limit=10

Answer (score 0):

The iTunes [API Documentation](http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html) says that you can use this URL to look up a specific artist:

https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?amgArtistId=468749

But they don't provide artist background. They do provide a link to the Artist Page on iTunes which does have the bio. Just note that following this link and scraping that information programmatically would be against the ToU for itunes.apple.com. And they probably have some type of infra in place to identify folks doing this and timeout those requests.